# Umbraco upload large files in media

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a requirements that the admin panel of Umbraco needs to be able to upload large files of videos such as a 2gb, 4gb.. I heard that .Net has a limit of 4gb or 2gb of upload (correct me if I'm wrong). So basically I already changed the `maxAllowedContentLength` such as below

```
<!-- Max file size limitation -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4257286400" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and because there are limits to the duration and upload size I also adjusted the execution time

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4257286400" executionTimeout="9999999" requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Now the problem is when I try to upload a 1gb of file the page just keeps on loading and nothing happens when I try to turn on debug logs I can see that it's being canceled due to large files. Now I don't know how to solve this as I really need for the user to be able to upload large files.

The option of uploading the file to a different site like youtube or vimeo is not an option. I really need to upload it to the site directly. Is there a way to achieve this in Umbraco?

Note: I already used some package available but none work like

[Import Media](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/import-media) - Already installed this but I don't know how it works. Like there are no new feature on the admin panel so I don't know what to look for here

Would really appreaciate some help here. I just want to be able to upload large files in Umbraco

Just to summarize this:

1. How to upload Large file in Umbraco Backend-Office because my settings is not allowing me to do so. Minimum filesize is 2gb
2. How to use Import Media Package if anyone have a chance to use this

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is caused by different dimensions for values in attributes:

1) `"maxAllowedContentLength"` specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in **bytes** (uint): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/

2) `"maxRequestLength"` sets the maximum request size in **kilobytes**(Int32):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yeah I did consider this. Previously I was getting an error of size limit when uploading and hence found out that it's in different size. One is kilo while the other is bytes and I had to modify it respectively

Comment: Could you update you question please so we can know that this possible issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error message are you getting about uploads "being canceled due to large files"?

AFAIK Umbraco doesn't have these kinds of limits by itself, it's all managed by IIS via the settings you've already found.

However I do seem to recall something about machine.config that might also set some of these properties and thus trump your local website settings. So that's something to check if you have access to that file (it'll be somewhere like C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config). Otherwise you might want to contact some hosting administrator/support and ask if there's a global limit set.

Comment: Thans for the reply. Did you happen to know how the Import Media package in Umbraco works?

Comment: No idea, sorry. But I wouldn't be too sure it even works with v7 - it's a very old package :-/ But it doesn't sound like it does much, to be honest. In newer Umbraco versions you should be able to drag/drop entire folders into Media at once, assuming of course that the files aren't too large.